# Rails model association for a soccer match. Match has two Country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

Any suggestions on how to set up this relationship? A `Match` has two `Country` on each side, right?

However, Rails Admin is complaining that this is not the right way.

```
create_table "countries", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "flag"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "matches", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "country_a"
  t.integer "country_b"
  t.integer "score_country_a"
  t.integer "score_country_b"
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :matches
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country_side_a, foreign_key: :country_a
  belongs_to :country_side_b, foreign_key: :country_b
end
```

How can I configure these relationships properly?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ultimately set up the relations:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches_a, foreign_key: :country_a, class_name: "Match"
  has_many :matches_b, foreign_key: :country_b, class_name: "Match"
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country_side_a, foreign_key: :country_a, class_name: "Country"
  belongs_to :country_side_b, foreign_key: :country_b, class_name: "Country"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

`Country` needs to have a `has_one :matches`, if you want a one to one mapping, or `has_many :matches` if you want a many to many relationship.

Have a read about how to set up a one to one/many relationship here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association